# Resizable and Draggable custom dialog in blazor server side

Tags: javascript, .net-core, modal-dialog, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am working on Blazor components in Core 3.1. I need to make a custom draggable dialog in blazor using only javscript(without jquery-ui). Can someone help me in achieving this. I tried some fiddles but controls inside them are not working.

Comment: Post your code.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a sample you can modify according to your requirements.
You can write this CSS in site.css or in the style tag

```
<style>
            #mydiv {
                position: absolute;
                z-index: 9;
                background-color: #f1f1f1;
                text-align: center;
                border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
            }
    
            #mydivheader {
                padding: 10px;
                cursor: move;
                z-index: 10;
                background-color: #2196F3;
                color: #fff;
            }
        </style>
```

In your blazor component

```
@page "/"
    
    @inject IJSRuntime JsRuntime;
    
        <h1>Draggable DIV Element</h1>
    
        <div id="mydiv">
            <div id="mydivheader">Header</div>
            <p>This is only one sample</p>
        </div>
    
    
    
        @code {
    
    
            protected override Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
            {
                if (firstRender)
                    JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("blazorjs.dragable");
    
                return base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
            }
    
        }
```

You write this any JavaScript (.js) file or in the script tag

```
<script>
    window.blazorjs = {
         dragable: function () {
            dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv"));
    
            function dragElement(elmnt) {
                var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
                if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
                    /* if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:*/
                    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
                } else {
                    /* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
                    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
                }
    
                function dragMouseDown(e) {
                    e = e || window.event;
                    e.preventDefault();
                    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
                    pos3 = e.clientX;
                    pos4 = e.clientY;
                    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
                    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
                    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
                }
    
                function elementDrag(e) {
                    e = e || window.event;
                    e.preventDefault();
                    // calculate the new cursor position:
                    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
                    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
                    pos3 = e.clientX;
                    pos4 = e.clientY;
                    // set the element's new position:
                    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
                    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
                }
    
                function closeDragElement() {
                    /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
                    document.onmouseup = null;
                    document.onmousemove = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
```

You can check code in blazorfiddle, https://blazorfiddle.com/s/uwjknuwx

I just copied from w3schools and implemented in blazor, https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_draggable.asp